# How to display the data from MongoDB in Reactjs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am constantly getting an error of: 'Cannot read property 'map' of undefined even though in the console it says username, name, membershipActive are being assigned values but not being used. So there seems to be a mistake with my mapping. If anyone can help me out, that would be great!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { getUserList } from "../services/backendCallService";
import axios from 'axios';

export default class ManageUsers extends Component {
  state = { user: {} };
  async componentDidMount() {
    const { data: user } = await getUserList();
    this.setState({ user });
  }

  getUsersList() {
    return this.state.userInfo.map(user => {
      const {username, name, membershipActive} = user;
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Manage Users</h3>
        <table className="table">
          <thead className="thead-light">
            <tr>
              <th>Username</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Membership Active</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.getUsersList()}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: You never set `userInfo` in your state, nor do you return anything from inside the `map`

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use a `map` function on an `object`, it's only allowed on `arrays`. Here is a working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-leftpad-ec7dk?file=/src/App.js). I have used dummy values for the `user` object for obvious reasons.

```js
state = { user: [] };

getUsersList() {
    if (this.state.user) {
      return this.state.user.map(user => (
         <tr>
          <td>{user.username}</td>
          <td>{user.name}</td>
          <td>{user.membershipActive}</td>
        </tr>
      ));
    }
  }
```